# Modded minecraft server crashes - not enough space, even tho there is plenty

Tags: server, partitioning, java, minecraft

**tl;dr:** using an ubuntu server for a modded minecraft server, it won't start or crash, because of lacking storage space, even tho there is more than enough. Do I need to enable more space or something?

I'm renting a dedicated linux server, to get started with server hosting for games and teamspeak, etc. Running a vanilla minecraft server works perfectly fine and there seem to be no problems. But with the modded minecraft it's not running so smoothly. I guess since the files itself are way larger/more there seems to be some default storage limit, that it is hitting. Every now and then, the server crashed because of lacking space, can't save backups and sometimes not even crash logs. I then need to delete some files, and it works for a while. All of my files take roughly 4 GB and the server is ordered with 140 GB. What do I need to do, to enable more than enough to the minecraft user/role, so I won't have this problem anymore. Or is there something else, that I might not know?

Thanks in advance for any help provided, I hope we can fix this issue.

Latest crash message from console:

`[16:53:30] [File IO Thread/WARN] [FML]: Unable to write forced chunk data to /home/minecraft_ftb/./DanielundTristan/DIM-343800852/forcedchunks.dat - chunkloading won't work java.io.IOException: No space left on device`

```
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:290) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeByte(DataOutputStream.java:153) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
    at net.minecraft.nbt.CompressedStreamTools.func_150663_a(CompressedStreamTools.java:107) ~[gi.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.nbt.CompressedStreamTools.func_74800_a(CompressedStreamTools.java:102) ~[gi.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.nbt.CompressedStreamTools.func_74795_b(CompressedStreamTools.java:152) ~[gi.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.common.ForgeChunkManager.lambda$saveWorld$1(ForgeChunkManager.java:958) ~[ForgeChunkManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.storage.ThreadedFileIOBase.func_75736_b(SourceFile:37) [bgx.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.storage.ThreadedFileIOBase.run(SourceFile:30) [bgx.class:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_272]
```

`

And the cash-log.txt is empty, because of missing space storage

`df` output:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            16438320       0  16438320   0% /dev
tmpfs            3293984   19004   3274980   1% /run
/dev/sda3        9220416 9204032         0 100% /
tmpfs           16469908       4  16469904   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           16469908       0  16469908   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2         999320  148352    782156  16% /boot
tmpfs            3293980       0   3293980   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs            3293980       0   3293980   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs            3293980       0   3293980   0% /run/user/1000
```

`df -i` output:

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           4109580    421 4109159    1% /dev
tmpfs          4117477   3039 4114438    1% /run
/dev/sda3       589824 132901  456923   23% /
tmpfs          4117477      2 4117475    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          4117477      3 4117474    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          4117477     18 4117459    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2        65536    313   65223    1% /boot
tmpfs          4117477     11 4117466    1% /run/user/0
tmpfs          4117477     11 4117466    1% /run/user/1001
tmpfs          4117477     11 4117466    1% /run/user/1000
```

and the `du -s` one:

```
minecraft_ftb@v2202004117865113423:~$ du -s /home/minecraft_ftb/
4173428 /home/minecraft_ftb/
```

from `sudo parted --list`

first comes this

```
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can
fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 2014 blocks) or continue with the
current setting?
Fix/Ignore?
```

then this:

```
Model: QEMU QEMU HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 150GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  3146kB  2097kB                     bios_grub
 2      3146kB  1077MB  1074MB  ext4
 3      1077MB  10.7GB  9661MB  ext4
```

Comment: Your root filesystem (/) appears to be only 10GB, not 140GB.

Comment: Did you partition HDD1? As part of your Ubuntu install (or before, or after)? Or did they set it up for you?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. The server came pre configurated. Most of the features were already installed. So I guess them. Btw thanks a lot for your help so far man, really appreciate it

Comment: Please add to your question the complete output of `sudo parted --list`

Comment: Your "modded minecraft server" has a bug. It's trying to write unlimited amounts of data to a temporary file. When it has used up all the space, it fails, and the temporary file is deleted, freeing the space. Read `man lsof` and use it while the server is running. Fix the bug.

Comment: So on the `sudo parted --list` it says 150GB storage, so why am I only using 10GB?

And how to solve the problem with the unlimited file, if I can't even start up the server atm?

Comment: You are using only 10GB because that's how your host set it up. Perhaps they made a typo -- contact your hosting provider and ask them to fix it. You could kludge around it yourself by adding another 129GB partition for your /home and data, but that leads to other problems in the future. The tmpfs bug might be in your startup script, or in your server app. No way to tell until you aren't out of space.

Comment: Well, very unfortunate news, but thanks for the help. Seems like I know the problem now. Just need to wait till monday, so the support is available again

Comment: While your "Modded minecraft server is running (and has been wunning for a while, before it fails) use these command strings: `sudo lsof / | awk '{if($7 > 1048576) print $7/1048576 "MB" " " $9 }' | sort -n -u` to list large, OPEN files, and `sudo lsof / | grep -E 'PID|\(deleted\)'` to see deleted but open files (they go away automatically when the process exits)

Comment: Okay, I will try, thanks a lot for all the help